# kubectl create secret docker-registry for all namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a local cluster used for testing and I'm starting it with a script I've written. In the script I'm using the command:

`kubectl create secret docker-registry myname --namespace mynamespace --docker-server "my.server.com" --docker-username "user" --docker-password "pass"`

This works fine for that namespace.

My question is if I can create the secret for ALL namespaces in a single command (including those who will be created later on) and not just for a particular namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to create the secret right now for each namespace:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu

for namespace in $(kubectl get namespaces -o=json | jq -r ".items | .[] | .metadata.name"); do
    kubectl create secret docker-registry myname --namespace "$namespace" --docker-server "my.server.com" --docker-username "user" --docker-password "pass" || true
done
```

However, there's no support out of the box for creating secrets in every new namespace going forward. To do that, you could look at extending Kubernetes by writing a custom operator. See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/